# How to post multiple buttons with python discord bot, everything I find is different, all of them make syntax errors

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a character creation post using buttons. I keep getting syntax errors and it won't recognize any button references I use. I am very new to all this so I'm not sure if I even have the name of the library right, and I can't seem to find good sources of information.
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ui import ButtonStyle, Button
import random
import time
^this is my import format

and here is the structure of my code

```
@Kanna.command()
    async def Adventure_time(ctx):
        class Button(*7, style: discord.Buttonstyle = ButtonStyle.green,
        label="strength" "agility" "constitution" "intelligence" "will" 
          "charisma""luck", custom_id= "str" "agt" "con" "int" "will" "cha" 
          "luck")
  
        CHSHT['AP'] += 3
        CHSHT['SP'] += 2

        while CHSHT['AP'] > 0:
          async def on_button_click(interaction):
            if interaction.component.label.startswith("Strength"):
              CHSHT['str'] += 1
              CHSHT['AP'] -= 1
            elif interaction.component.label.startswith("Agility"):
              CHSHT['agt'] += 1
              CHSHT['AP'] -= 1
            elif interaction.component.label.startswith("Constitution"):
              CHSHT['con'] += 1
              CHSHT['AP'] -= 1
            elif interaction.component.label.startswith("Intelligence"):
              CHSHT['int'] += 1
              CHSHT['AP'] -= 1
            elif interaction.component.label.startswith("Will"):
              CHSHT['will'] += 1
              CHSHT['AP'] -= 1
            elif interaction.component.label.startswith("Charisma"):
              CHSHT['cha'] += 1
              CHSHT['AP'] -= 1
            elif interaction.component.label.startswith("Luck"):
              CHSHT['luck'] += 1
              CHSHT['AP'] -= 1
          break
        class Button(*7, style: discord.Buttonstyle = ButtonStyle.primary, 
        label="Melee" "Ranged" "Craft" "Spell" "Blessing" "Perform" "Survival", 
        custom_id= "mle" "rgd" "cft" "spl" "bls" "prf" "srv")
        while CHSHT['SP'] > 0:
```

Well, I expected to find out about a few gramar sytax errrors, then see some buttons that most likely
sent an error message to the console until I sorted out the proper way to connect them, but it wouldn't even get that far, I only got the bot running a couple times, and trying the command didn't return anything but errors about not recognizing ButtonStyle. I tried to adjust the import but it wouldn't accept anything else I tried. There was a line someone said needed to be put under the on_startup command, I had to remove that for indent purposes, and I wasn't using that persons reference, but did it need to be replaced with something?
I am aware of the potential super newb mistake I'm likely making here, please understand I've only been learning since jan 20th. verry newb here... any assistance would be super awesome.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. You should take a look at [this official example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/tic_tac_toe.py).
Note: Include a full traceback error when you ask a question; it helps a lot !

Comment: the only answer I get is referencing a 2 year old post giving the most confusing example I have ever seen. 
I think I'm being trolled here

Comment: It seems like your issue might be related to Python itself, given the numerous syntax errors. Remember, if you encounter an error, please __provide a full traceback error along with your code__. This will help us to address the problem.

Additionally, I encourage you to join *[the official discord.py server here](https://discord.gg/r3sSKJJ)* for immediate assistance.

Answer (score 0):

i'm still pretty new to python/discord.py but maybe you should try using a view and add it to the command.
example:

```py
class Bus(ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        

    @ui.button(label="label", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
    async def window(self, interaction:discord.Interaction, button:discord.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_message(content="Live beyond the window.")
    @ui.button(label="lab",style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
    async def wi(self, interaction:discord.Interaction, buttton:discord.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_message(content="wow")



@Kanna.command()
async def Adventure_time(ctx):
    await ctx.send(content="content",view=Bus())
```

the example code i showed will have the message "content" and the 2 buttons directly underneath it.
also im pretty sure you can't define a class within a command, but then again i am still new. I hope this helps.